# Create CRM Organizations on Load Balancing network

Tags: dynamics-crm, load-balancing, crm, organization, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to understand how to create CRM Organization on Load Balancing network.

I've three web servers (Web01, Web 02, Web03); three application servers (App01, App02, App03) and a SQL Server (SQL01). I already have Load Balancer setup and there is already one organizaiton setup by someone on all web servers. This organization is Internet Facing. Now I want to create one more Organization on same set of Web Servers. Can anyone please help me understand how to setup new Organization on Load Balancer in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

An important point to know is that there is a difference between a CRM deployment, and the organizations deployed.

The deployment consist of one or more CRM Server, and a SQL Server that can be clustered. A different server can be used as ReportServer and an Exchange Server can be configured as the email router.

Once the servers are deployed, one or many organizations can be configured using the CRM Deployment manager, on one of the front-end CRM Server. All the front-end (load balanced) server can be used to access any organizations configured in the deployment, based on the current user's credentials. When configuring the organization, the Report Server that should be used is assigned to the organization.

Also, if you are using IFD (Internet Facing Deployment), every organizations should have their own DNS entry (orgId.theprefixchoosen.mydomain.intra) that is pointing to the load balancer's IP address, so that CRM can route the users to the appropriate organization. More can be found in Microsoft's documents on configuring IFD.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the new org is no different that normal.  You would do this via Deployment Manager on 1 of the servers.  This will basically create the needed SQL DB and associated ocnfig entries.  To get the IFD portion working, you will also potentially need to add DNS entries to route traffic for that new orgname to your servers.